# type=file - should get the value in array instead of single value valuename

Tags: javascript, input-type-file

Here am passing the file value to another page **new.jsp**. As per attached Snapshot i have multiple of **choose file option** as number of rows exist per condition.
From the below code, i could get the value of the filename(but while saving in DB only the last one is getting saved for all the filename as commmon) **but i couldnt get all the file names in array.**

Can someone pls guide how to get all the filenames through array. Thanks in Adv.
If i get the filenames in array for all the rows in the table , i can split and save each filemname in DB according to each row.

Attaching the snapshot for refernce: Browse column with multiple column for type=file according to the condition.
[image]

```
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" multiple="multiple"/>


 $('input[type=file]').change(function () {
console.dir(this.files[0]);
var filename = this.files[0]['file1'];
alert(filename);
$.ajax({
        url : "new.jsp",
        data : {filename : filename}, 
        type: 'post',
        success : function(data) 
        {
        }
       }); 
                                 });  
                                 
**new.jsp** Page

<%

String filename = request.getParameter("filename");
System.out.println("newfilename"+filename);
session.setAttribute("filename", filename);

%>
```

Comment: you are getting an array (or array like structure at least) called `this.files` ... and you are accessing `this.files` as if it were an array using `this.files[0]`- so, why do you think **i couldnt get all the file names in array** ?

Comment: also, I don't think `this.files[0]` has a property called `filesToUpload[]` - that's probably another issue ... a "File" object is documented [here - File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) ... `this.files` (a FileList) is documented [here - FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)

Comment: @Bravo , i have edited the ID.. It must be` var filename = this.files[0]['file1'];`
So should i try using Filelist to get all the values of the row from the table?

Comment: I don't think a `File` object has a property called `file1` - you ARE using a FileList ... that's what `this.files` is! Have you even read the documentation I linked for you?